# How do I use a link in my inline if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a inline if statement that checks the length of a string or if it is null. If it is null, or has a length of 4 it will display "Currently Unavailable", otherwise it will display the string. here is my inline statement

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) ||
 ((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length == 4)) ? "Currently Unavailable " : 
   Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT"))%>
```

I want to take that statement a step further so that users can click to call using their phones.

```
<a href='tel:+<%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%>'><%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%></a>
```

How do I combine the 2 so that it displays `currently unavailable` when it needs to(without creating a link) and generating the link when it passes the if statement?

Comment: Obligatory cross site scripting warning as a result of writing out raw HTML based on user inputted text.  Either avoid writing out the user's content as raw HTML, or be very careful about how you sanitize the input.

Answer (score 1):

One options is to create a nice helper method within your page class:

```
protected String PhoneNumber(String phone)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) || phone.length == 4
        ? "currently unavailable"
        : String.Format("<a href=\"tel:+{0}\">{0}</a>", phone);
}
```

Then:

```
<%# PhoneNumber(DataBinder.Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two statements to produce:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) || ((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length == 4)) ?
    "Currently Unavailable " :
    "<a href='tel:+" + Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT") + "'>" + Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT") + "</a>" %>
```